# Jackson JSON chokes when deserializing a Collection

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Java 11, Spring Boot 2.5 and Jackson 2.12 here. I have the following Java classes:

```
// using lombok annos to generate getters & setters
@Data
public class ExamUnit implements Comparable<ExamUnit> {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String displayName;
    private Long order;
    private Exam exam;

    // compareTo, equals & hashCode are necessary so that the TreeSet below sorts ExamUnits
    // correctly, according to my needs
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ExamUnit other) {
        if (this.equals(other)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.order < other.order) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ExamUnit examUnit = (ExamUnit) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, examUnit.name) &&
                Objects.equals(displayName, examUnit.displayName) &&
                Objects.equals(order, examUnit.order);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, displayName, order);
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Data
public class Exam {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String displayName;
    private SortedSet<ExamUnit> units = new TreeSet<>();

}
```

Then I have an "exam" JSON string:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "science",
  "displayName": "Science Exam",
  "units": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "chemistry",
      "displayName": "Chemistry Unit",
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "biology",
      "displayName": "Biology Unit",
      "order": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This is valid JSON, as you can verify yourself. And it does appear to follow the model of the Java types correctly.

Then I have some code to read the string and deserialize it:

```
@Test
public void deserializeExamJson() {

    String examJson = "{\n" +
            "  \"id\": 1,\n" +
            "  \"name\": \"science\",\n" +
            "  \"displayName\": \"Science Exam\",\n" +
            "  \"units\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": 1,\n" +
            "      \"name\": \"chemistry\",\n" +
            "      \"displayName\": \"Chemistry Unit\",\n" +
            "      \"order\": 1\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"id\": 2,\n" +
            "      \"name\": \"biology\",\n" +
            "      \"displayName\": \"Biology Unit\",\n" +
            "      \"order\": 2\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "  ]\n" +
            "}";

    Exam exam = null;
    try {
        exam = objectMapper.readValue(examJson, Exam.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    assertThat(exam.getName()).isEqualTo("science");

}
```

When this test runs, it fails with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected VALUE_STRING: need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of java.util.SortedSet)
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 6, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.me.myapp.Exam["units"])
```

Comment: Why do you have an `Exam` field in your `ExamUnit`?

Comment: In reality these are JPA entities and I need bi-directionality (if I have an ExamUnit, I need cascaded access to its parent Exam). I've omitted all the JPA annotations since they are not relevant to the question. I am not opposed to adding a `@JsonIgnore` to the exam field though, if you think thats is necessary for Jackson's sake.

Comment: But FWIW the same exception arises even if I comment the exam field out.

Comment: Ideally you should have a DTO layer. But aside from that, what if you try a `Set` (hashset?) or `List`

Comment: Yep, same exact exception if I make it `Set<ExamUnit>` or `List<ExamUnit>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ExamUnit class annotate your property `private Exam exam;` with `@JsonIgnore`

Comment: Yep this was it -- thanks! Wee bit of a cryptic exception message though...